# How to merge two images in imagemagick (php api)

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm a beginner and facing following issue. I need to merge two imagefiles with imagemagick api -> so I'm using php not the comandline.

I have a BG:
[image]

And I have another image which has a transparent section in the middle:
[image]

The Endresult should look like this:
[image]

I would be very thankfull if anybody can help me out with this. I tried it in numeros ways, but without any success sofar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this: http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/mergeImageLayers

I think something like this should work

```
function mergeImages()
{
    // you should find the correct layerMethodType by yourself,
    // here the available ones: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php

    $layerMethodType = imagick::LAYERMETHOD_COMPARECLEAR;
    $img1 = new \Imagick(realpath("bg.png"));

    $img2 = new \Imagick(realpath("play.png"));
    $img1->addImage($img2);
    $img1->setImageFormat('png');

    $result = $img1->mergeImageLayers($layerMethodType);
    header("Content-Type: image/png");

    echo $result->getImageBlob();
}
```

Comment: Thx I allready tried this one. There is no output/image also no error. As I suppose adding this code to my side I should see a result?

Comment: Got it now working thx